# Salesforce Opportunity Validation Rule

Tags: validation, salesforce

I am working on a validation rule on the Opportunity object.  The goal is to bypass a validation rule if an item from a Multi-Select picklist is selected, otherwise the code should fire

Here's what I have so far - everything works except the exception portion - NOT(CONTAINS('Campaign_Tactic__c','Call Monitoring')))

So the validation rule should fire unless the Call Monitoring multi-select is chosen.

The Validation Rule should prevent an Opportunity Save if:

- **Opportunity Record Type** = True
- **Opportunity Stage** = Closed Won or Proposal Request
- **Landing Page Setup Field** = blank/no data
- **Campaign Tactic Multi-Select field** = does not contain the Call Monitoring Option

  ```
  AND (
      RecordType.DeveloperName = "New_Opportunity",
      OR ( 
          ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"), 
          ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Proposal Request")
      ), 
      AND ( 
          ISBLANK(TEXT(Landing_Page_Setup__c))
      ),
      (!CONTAINS('Campaign_Tactic__c','Call Monitoring'))
  )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Salesforce Formula Function Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5), it's important to note

> The CONTAINS function does not support multi-select picklists. Use INCLUDES to see if a multi-select picklist has a specific value.

Additionally, the first argument you're providing to `CONTAINS()` is a quoted string literal, not a field reference, and the outer parentheses are extraneous:

```
    (!CONTAINS('Campaign_Tactic__c','Call Monitoring'))
```

Your final clause should use [`INCLUDES()`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5), as:

```
!INCLUDES(Campaign_Tactic__c, 'Call Monitoring')
```

Note also that `AND()` with a single argument can be replaced by the argument alone, so

```
AND ( 
    ISBLANK(TEXT(Landing_Page_Setup__c))
),
```

reduces to

```
ISBLANK(TEXT(Landing_Page_Setup__c)),
```

You need the `TEXT()` call only if that field is a picklist.

Comment: That works perfectly - thanks for the info & appreciate the help!